# For $f_n\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ if $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ show that $f(x+\frac{1}{n})\to f(x)$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ ($C_0(\mathbb{R})$ continuos function of compact support). Suppose that $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Show that  in the space  then $f(x+\frac{1}{n})\to f(x)$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, choose some $f_{N}$ such that $\|f_{N}-f\|_{L^{1}}<\epsilon$, then 
\begin{align*}
\int|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|dx&\leq\int|f(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x+1/n)|dx+\int|f_{N}(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x)|dx\\
&~~~~+\int|f_{N}(x)-f(x)|dx\\
&=2\|f_{N}-f\|_{L^{1}}+\int|f_{N}(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x)|dx\\
&<2\epsilon+\int|f_{N}(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x)|dx,
\end{align*}
but $f_{N}(x+1/n)\rightarrow f_{N}(x)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for every $x$, and that $|f_{N}(x+1/n)|\leq(\sup|f_{N}|)\chi_{\{|x|\leq M+1\}}$ for all $n$ and $x$, where $\text{supp}(f_{N})\subseteq\{|x|\leq M\}$, so 
\begin{align*}
\int|f_{N}(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x)|dx\rightarrow 0,~~~~n\rightarrow\infty,
\end{align*}
by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, so for some $n_{0}$, 
\begin{align*}
\int|f_{N}(x+1/n)-f_{N}(x)|dx<\epsilon,~~~~n\geq n_{0}.
\end{align*}